# What is SMSISTUB (Win 16 Subsystem)?

Tags: windows, 16-bit

This morning when I logged on to my work computer, I got the following "Application: SMSISTUB" message:

> The Win 16 Subsystem has insufficient
>   resources to continue running.  Click
>   on OK, close your applications [I only
>   had one application running at the
>   time], and restart your machine.

What the heck is this all about?

Comment: SMSISTUB is part if the Systems Management Server, do as heavyd suggested, contact yor IT department about the issue

Answer (score 0):

The Win 16 subsystem is the Windows emulation layer that allows your computer to run 16-bit applications on a 32-bit computer.  Microsoft has a nice [troubleshooting guide](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;314106) to work through problems with the Win 16 subsystem.

My guess would be that the application that is using the Win 16 subsystem is probably an old custom built app that you use for work, so I would also suggest getting in touch with your work's IT support, they may already have experienced this issue with your particular app.